# New to JS, trying to stop my div from counting once the counting has completed

Tags: javascript, scroll, counter

Basically i'm a beginner at JS, I'm trying to make this div start counting up when the div scrolls into view and stop counting once its finished counting. I managed to get it kind of working briefly but everytime I scrolled it would start counting again.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
let stats = document.getElementById('.container-stats');

stats.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
 function counter(id, start, end, duration) {
  let obj = document.getElementById(id),
   current = start,
   range = end - start,
   increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
   step = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
   timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += increment;
    obj.textContent = current;
    if (current == end) {
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
   }, step);
 }
 counter("count1", 0, 6, 3000);
 counter("count2", 100, 40, 3000);
 counter("count3", 499000, 500000, 3000);
 counter("count4", 0, 10, 3000);
 counter("count5", 0, 12, 3000);
 counter("count6", 0, 10, 3000);
});
```

Comment: You've set it up so that the event will fire every time you scroll. So when do you want it to stop?

Comment: I want it to stop once its finished counting. its basically trying to get it to start counting when I scroll to that section of the page and then stop counting once its completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `removeEventListener`.

First you should move the lambda in the `addEventListener` to a function, name it `startCounting`.

```
function startCounting {
 function counter(id, start, end, duration) {
  let obj = document.getElementById(id),
   current = start,
   range = end - start,
   increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
   step = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
   timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += increment;
    obj.textContent = current;
    if (current == end) {
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
   }, step);
 }
 counter("count1", 0, 6, 3000);
 counter("count2", 100, 40, 3000);
 counter("count3", 499000, 500000, 3000);
 counter("count4", 0, 10, 3000);
 counter("count5", 0, 12, 3000);
 counter("count6", 0, 10, 3000);

 stats.removeEventListener("scroll", startCounting); // this should detach the scroll event from the stats element
}
```

Then use it like this,

```
stats.addEventListener("scroll", startCounting);
```

The difference is that `startCounting` method will call the `removeEventListener` in the end.

Comment: Where in my code do I put the 

stats.addEventListener("scroll", startCounting);

Comment: @ryan. replace it with the third line in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
let stats = document.getElementById('container-stats');
let current = 0;

stats.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
 function counter(id, start, end, duration) {
  if(current !== undefined) {
  let obj = document.getElementById(id),
   current = start,
   range = end - start,
   increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
   step = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
   timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += increment;
    obj.textContent = current;
    if (current == end) {
     clearInterval(timer);
    }
   }, step);
  }
 }
 counter("count1", 0, 6, 3000);
 counter("count2", 100, 40, 3000);
 counter("count3", 499000, 500000, 3000);
 counter("count4", 0, 10, 3000);
 counter("count5", 0, 12, 3000);
 counter("count6", 0, 10, 3000);

 current = undefined;
});
```

If I got you correct, you asked for one session scroll and count right? There you go